# Moq verify method signature sees invocations but doesn't match on them?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have an interface like so:

```
public interface IStatisticsCollector : IDisposable
{
    Task Measure(string metricName, decimal value, IDictionary<string, string> tags = null);
}
```

I am injecting this `IStatisticsCollector` into my class and using it like this:

```
var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
await dataCollector.Measure("rbk_init", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
...
await dataCollector.Measure("rbk_compiled", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
...
```

Setting up my unit test to verify that I am recording all the statistics points I want, I mock the `IStatisticsCollector`:

```
private readonly Mock<IStatisticsCollector> _statisticsCollector = new Mock<IStatisticsCollector>();
_statisticsCollector.Setup(x => x.Measure(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<long>(), It.IsAny<IDictionary<string, string>>())).Verifiable();
```

When I run my unit test, my verification fails on this line:

```
//assert
_statisticsCollector.Verify(
    x => x.Measure(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<long>(), It.IsAny<IDictionary<string, string>>()), Times.Exactly(5));
```

...with the following message:

```
Moq.MockException : 
Expected invocation on the mock exactly 5 times, but was 0 times: x => x.Measure(It.IsAny<string>(), (decimal)It.IsAny<long>(), It.IsAny<IDictionary<string, string>>())

Configured setups: 
IStatisticsCollector x => x.Measure(It.IsAny<string>(), (decimal)It.IsAny<long>(), It.IsAny<IDictionary<string, string>>())

Performed invocations: 
IStatisticsCollector.Measure("rbk_init", 31, null)
IStatisticsCollector.Measure("rbk_compiled", 35, null)
IStatisticsCollector.Measure("rbk_stored", 36, null)
IStatisticsCollector.Measure("rbk_db_updated", 352, null)
IStatisticsCollector.Measure("rbk_completed", 361, null)
   at Moq.Mock.VerifyCalls(Mock targetMock, InvocationShape expectation, LambdaExpression expression, Times times, String failMessage) in C:\projects\moq4\src\Moq\Mock.cs:line 378
```

... this was strange because it looks like it captured 5 matching invocations, but apparently didn't consider any of them to actually be matches.  Now I postulated this might be related to the fact that the stopwatch's `ElapsedMilliseconds` was a long but the interface was expecting a decimal (with an implicit cast), so I changed the verify to look for `It.IsAny<decimal>()`, but that got me an unexpected result:

```
Moq.MockException : 
Expected invocation on the mock exactly 5 times, but was 1 times: x => x.Measure(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<decimal>(), It.IsAny<IDictionary<string, string>>())

Configured setups: 
IStatisticsCollector x => x.Measure(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<decimal>(), It.IsAny<IDictionary<string, string>>())

Performed invocations: 
IStatisticsCollector.Measure("rbk_init", 28, null)
   at Moq.Mock.VerifyCalls(Mock targetMock, InvocationShape expectation, LambdaExpression expression, Times times, String failMessage) in C:\projects\moq4\src\Moq\Mock.cs:line 378
```

It found one... and only one.  There doesn't seem to be an exception thrown, so I don't know why there would only be one.

I also noted the null value on the optional argument, and tried to verify against a null value instead of an `IDictionary<string, string>`, but this was similarly fruitless.

Can someone explain this behavior?  What do I need to do to fix my test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

THis line will always fail:

```
_statisticsCollector.Verify(
    x => x.Measure(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<long>(), It.IsAny<IDictionary<string, string>>()), Times.Exactly(5));
```

This happens because you are saying to the mock that it needs to receive a long in the second argument, BUT the interface says that in the second argument it will receive a decimal:

```
public interface IStatisticsCollector : IDisposable
{
    Task Measure(string metricName, decimal value, IDictionary<string, string> tags = null);
}
```

Since a decimal can't be a long, your verificatin will always fail.

Comment: Ah! I see.  So I don't necessarily need to have the same "signature" with the `It.IsAny<>` construct in the setup and the verify.  This makes perfect sense, thanks.

Comment: You actually don't need to have the exact same types. Imagine that your interface received on the second argument an object, but you wanted to verify any call that the second argument was a string. In this case, since a string is also an object, you could use It.IsAny<string>() instead of It.IsAny<object>(). Sometimes you want to do asserts like this.